# Variable dump shows data but returns as undefined

Tags: coldfusion, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

Hopefully this is a "DOH" moment but I can't figure out why this is happening. I am using a service object to get the members of a group in Google's Directory API. After creating the service object I used the following lines to test

```
<cfset themembers = groupservice.members().list("[My Group Key]").execute()>
<cfdump var="#themembers#">
<cfoutput>
   Isnull? #isNull(themembers.etag)#<br />
   SKExists? #structKeyExists(themembers,"etag")#<br />
   Is Defined? #isDefined("themembers.etag")#
</cfoutput>
```

The resulting output of the code looks like this [image: screenshot]

Looking at the dump I can see there is data in the etag field as well as an array of members. However, when I tried to output the key value I was getting an undefined error. I wrote a test output line and it's showing as NULL and not defined while the key DOES exist.

How is this possible when the dump of the variable clearly shows data? What am I missing here?

@Leigh

```
<cfdump var="#groupservice.members()#">
<cfdump var="#groupservice.members().list('[groupkey]')#">
```

Here are the dumps from the 2 lines above. The list method simply returns the groupkey name that i'm passing in - it's only after I run the execute method do I actually get the list of members (output in first image) but just like with the etag - it tells me members is undefined.
[image: sshot1]

Comment: So what does it actually contain (string, number, class, ...)? Can you dump the `groupservice.members().list("[My Group Key]")` so we can see the `execute()` method signature? At a guess, `themembers` probably is not a CF structure in the strictest sense. Most structure functions accept any complex object, but the results may not be exactly the same as with "real" structures....

Comment: What is the line of code that produces the error?

Comment: Also, it may not apply here but ... it is possible for a structure "key" to exist, but the "value" of that key is `null` or undefined.

Comment: @Leigh - I edited the original question with a couple dumps - the list method simply returned the groupkey name I entered.

Comment: @Dan - I replaced the line causing the error (a simple output of #themembers.etag#) with the isdefined check - which shows as NO in the output

Comment: (Edit) Thanks. Still hard to tell what kind of object it is, especially since the api says it uses generics. What do you get if you dump the class name, ie `#theList = groupservice.members().list('[groupkey]'); writeDump(theList.getClass().name);`?  Do the same for `themembers`.  Also, though they are probably not *real* structures, can you dump the key names for both `theList` and `themembers`. ie Use `structKeyList()`

Comment: Also - if I try to do something like `<cfset GK ="#groupservice.members().list('[groupkey]')#">` and then try to output `#GK.groupKey#` - get the same type of undefined error - **element groupkey is undefined in GK**

Comment: @Leigh - that's what has me so puzzled - when I get the key list it displays what I'm seeing in the dumps: For `thelist` its **groupKey** and for `themembers` it's **etag,kind,members** but outputting any of their values comes back as undefined in the structure. When i `<cfdump var="#theList.getClass().name#">` I get **com.google.api.services.admin.directory.Directory$Members$List** and for `<cfdump var="#theMember.getClass().name#">` I get **com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Members**

Comment: (Edit) @Aces'nEights - *RE: that's what has me so puzzled* Trying to remember the exact circumstances, but I have seen *something* similar to that before. IIRC, the structure key was defined, but the "value" for that key is null, so isNull() returned true and isDefined() false. The part  I have not heard of is what you described - ie that dumping the object seems to show that the key *does* have a value. (Update) My guess is it may be related to the fact that those objects are not *really* structures (despite what cfdump says), so the values cannot be accessed using dot notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Apparently this falls under the general rule of "Never trust CFDump. Sometimes it lies." Case in point, the variable `themembers` is not really a structure. It is an instance of the [Members](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/admin/directory/model/Members.html) class. Instead of using dot notation, try invoking the relevant methods of the class:

```
<cfset eTag = themembers.getETag()>
<cfset membersArray = themembers.getMembers()>
..
```

**Longer Answer:**

While CFDump is a good debugging tool, it tends to favor "pretty presentation" over accuracy, so you cannot always trust what you see. The reason it displays `themembers` as a "struct" is because ColdFusion  [automatically matches Java types to ColdFusion types](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/using-java-objects.html). If you take a look at the class hierarchy of [Members](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/admin/directory/model/Members.html), you can see it implements [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (via AbstractMap), which is automatically matched to a CF structure. Hence why CFDump (misleadingly) displays it as one.

```
- com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Members
- com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson
- com.google.api.client.util.GenericData
- java.util.AbstractMap   
- java.lang.Object
```

Although java objects are similar to structures, in some respects, they are not the same thing. So the results from certain functions may differ from what you would normally expect for structures, which is what happened here. i.e. You can view some of the property names, like you can with structure keys, but you cannot access the key/property values directly.

That said, technically you *should* have been able to access the "eTag" and "members" properties with dot notation. The reason being that CF applies a bit of syntactic sugar to certain java objects to allow direct access of properties using dot notation. Just as if they were regular structure keys.

> ColdFusion can automatically invoke get_PropertyName_() and
>   set_PropertyName_(value) methods if a Java class conforms to the
>   JavaBeans pattern. As a result, you can set or get the property by
>   referencing it directly, without having to explicitly invoke a method.

However, as the docs note later on, there are some exceptions. This class appears to be one of them. So you will need to call the appropriate get*PropertyName()* methods explicitly. Ultimately, that is probably the best practice anyway, given that direct access does not always work.

*Example:*

```
// Simulate Members object 
obj = createObject("java", "com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Members").init();
// Initialize property values
obj.setEtag("If you are seeing this text, it worked.");
obj.setMembers( [] );

writeOutput("<br>IsNull? "& isNull(obj.etag));
writeOutput("<br>Key List: "& structKeyList(obj));
writeOutput("<br>Exists? "& structKeyExists(obj, "etag"));
writeOutput("<br>IsDefined? "& IsDefined("obj.etag"));
writeOutput("<br>getETag(): "& obj.getETag());
writeDump(var=obj.getMembers(), label="getMembers()");
```

*Results:*

```
IsNull? YES
Key List: etag,members
Exists? YES
IsDefined? NO
getETag(): If you are seeing this text, it worked.
getMembers(): (empty array)
```

Comment: TYVM - calling the respective getproperty() method explicitly did the trick. Gonna have to keep the "CFDUMP sometimes lies" in the memory banks for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The way I get around the undefined structure values is to use structKeyArray to make an array of the keys in the struct.  Then, loop over the array to check if the struct key exists.  Example:

```
 //result is a structure which can have undefined values
  myAry = structKeyArray(result);
    myLen = arrayLen(myAry);
    for (i=1; i <= myLen;i=i+1){
     if(!structKeyExists(result, "#myAry[i]#")){
      result[myAry[i]] = "";
     }
    }
```

Of course, you might not want blank strings, but in my circumstance, that is what I was looking for if it didn't exist.